# SQL. How to take value from one column and pass It to another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I'm using *SQL-Server 2008*. How to take value from one column and pass It to another column?

As you see in sample data below there are 4 columns. Where I need to take column name (in this case `UserName`) and pass It to `FieldName` column and value from `UserName` column pass to `Value` column.

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
GroupId   UserName     FieldName    Value        
1         John Smith   Foo          28
1         John Smith   Bar          2
1         John Smith   FooBar       11
1         John Smith   Bizz         22
2         Peter Jones  Foo          4
2         Peter Jones  Bar          13
2         Peter Jones  FooBar       27
2         Peter Jones  Bizz         23
```

---

**DESIRED RESULTS**

```
GroupId   FieldName    Value         
1         Foo          28
1         Bar          2
1         FooBar       11
1         Bizz         22
1         UserName     John Smith
2         Foo          4
2         Bar          13
2         FooBar       27
2         Bizz         23
2         UserName     Peter Jones
```

How could I achieve It? By using `PIVOT`? But I'm not sure how to merge pivoted data to existing column. Have you any ideas? If something unclear - ask me, I'll try provide more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select GroupId,   FieldName,    Value      
from table 
union 
select distinct GroupId, 'username',  UserName   
from table
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to `PIVOT` , just a simple `UNION ALL` will do the job :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.groupID,'USERNAME',t.userName
FROM YourTable t
UNION ALL
SELECT s.groupID,s.FieldName,s.Value
FROM YourTable s
```

Comment: Exactly 1 and a half  minute before me, how long do you it took me to write it? @Paparazzi

Comment: So, it is still a duplicate answer

Comment: Actually no, `UNION ALL` will perform better. @Paparazzi

Comment: Oh, excuse me, big difference

Comment: Tiny as it is, it's still a difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.* 
FROM tbl
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
        (GroupId, FieldName, Value),
        (GroupId, 'UserName', UserName)
) t(GroupId, FieldName, Value)
```

Also check a small information about `UNPIVOT` and `VALUES` from my [post](http://blog.devart.com/is-unpivot-the-best-way-for-converting-columns-into-rows.html)